# How to remove nodes above and below somewhere in the document

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Assuming I have an instance of `HtmlNode` pointing to table, how can I remove all nodes above and below it?
we can assume table is in the same level of html and body tag

```
<html>
<body>
<p>please remove me</p>

<table>
....
</table>

<p>please remove me</p>
<a> ... </a>
.
<img>...</img>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your HTML sample (and commonly it is), `<table>` is child of `<body>`, they are not at the same level. Assuming that `table` is a variable of type `HtmlNode` pointing to the `<table>` element, you can do this way :

```
var nodes = table.SelectNodes("following-sibling::*[1] | preceding-sibling::*[1]");
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    node.Remove();
}
```

**brief explanation about XPath being used :**

- `following-sibling::*[1]` : select *direct following sibling* element regardless of the element name.
- `preceding-sibling::*[1]` : select *direct preceding sibling* element regardless of the element name.
- `|` : XPath union operator to combine two different XPath expressions

Comment: correct. what i meant was the same level of body actually. thank you for your detailed answer. it works perfectly